# Git diff command from shell script

Tags: bash, git, shell

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

git log -1 | grep -w '^commit' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | git show | grep -w '^index' | cut -d ' ' -f2 > tmp_out

while read -r arg
do
        arg1=${arg[@]:0:10}
        arg2=${arg[@]:23:10}

        cmd="git diff ${arg1}^ ${arg2}"
        echo $cmd
        $cmd
done <tmp_out
```

Which should in theory show all merge conflicts occurred during git merge. Script gives an error:

```
git diff <SHA1>^ <SHA2>
error: object <SHA1> is a blob, not a commit
error: object <SHA1> is a blob, not a commit
fatal: ambiguous argument '<SHA1>^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

(SHA1 and SHA2 are index hashes) But when I copy the command manually and run:

```
git diff <SHA1>^ <SHA2>
```

it works. So my question is: Why shell script can not execute `git diff <SHA1>^ <SHA2>`?

Comment: When you run the command manually, are you by any chance using a Windows CMD? The `^` has special meaning there and is ignored.

Comment: `git show` doesn't read its standard input, so `... | git show` can be replaced with just `git show`. Fortunately you wanted to show the `HEAD` commit and that's the default. Note that when the `HEAD` commit *is* a merge commit, it has two parents and using just `^` (which means `^1`) would be wrong anyway. You're getting lucky (or unlucky, which is the same thing) when doing the command by hand in that the `^` is getting discarded.

Comment: (You might also look into `git diff-tree` and in particular how it handles merges when using `-c` or `--cc`. See the DIFF FORMAT FOR MERGES section.)

Comment: @j6t I use windows os, and cmdr, can it be the problem?

Comment: Sure, it's a problem. In a Windows CMD, you have to type `^^` for every `^` that you want the command to see. A lone `^` is just ignored. (I don't know its meaning.)

Comment: @torek thank you, removing ^ solved my problem.

Comment: @j6t adding additional ^ did not fix problem.

Comment: If "the problem" is that you now also get an error on the command line, then things are as expected. At least you get the same error in the script and in the manual invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove `^` completely. Answer from @torek in comments.

```
#!/bin/bash                                           
                                                        
git show | grep -w '^index' | cut -d ' ' -f2 > tmp_out
                                                      
while read -r arg                                     
do                                                    
        arg1=${arg[@]:0:10}                           
        arg2=${arg[@]:23:10}                          
                                                      
        cmd="git diff ${arg1} ${arg2}"              
        echo $cmd                                     
        $cmd                                          
done <tmp_out
```